# Linux print uptime in short format

Tags: linux, ubuntu, uptime

When uptime normally prints out like this

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ uptime -p
up 4 days, 1 hour, 43 minutes
```

How could I get it to print out in a shorter format, something like:

```
up 4d, 1h, 43m
```

I need to keep it short to display it on a 1602 lcd screen.
I would also prefer a oneliner but that's not neccessary.

Comment: Anyway, you can do this with a trivial `sed` command.

Comment: Hint: write a regular expression that captures a number followed by a space and word, and replaces it with the number and the first letter of the word.

Answer (score 0):

This was way simpler question than I first thought, just replace the words...

```
uptime -p | sed 's/up\s*//g' | sed 's/\s*days/d/g' | sed 's/\s*hours/h/g' | sed 's/\s*minutes/m/g'
```

produces:

```
4d, 2h, 12m
```

Comment: You only need one `sed` and no `/g`s: `uptime -p | sed 's/up\s*//; s/\s*days/d/; s/\s*hours/h/; s/\s*minutes/m/'`